# HTTP\WebSocket server under Cordova application

Tags: android, cordova, sockets, tcp, udp

I've faced an issue with creating any kind of servers under Cordova application. Wondering if it possible at all.

**Scenario**

Let's imagine that we have a decentralized network of devices (tablets, phones) from one tablet to a huge network of 20+ devices and can be more. These devices must handle synchronization between each other and it can be implemented as HTTP server or WebSocket server, etc...

Each device have installed Cordova application and our goal is to make these devices discoverable in a network (*I was thinking about UDP datagrams for discovery*) and these devices must synchronize data between them (*simple TCP connections and JSON objects*).

**Question**

For this scenario we need to have an access to a network layer in Cordova application. So, our Cordova application when running onto device can be as server and as client as well. The question here is **how to implement UDP\TCP server in Cordova application, since we have only client implementations?**

---

P.S. I was trying plugins like *cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-udp*, *cordova-plugin-websocket* and *cordova-plugin-websocket-server* but it still doesn't work properly (*I'd like to say it's not working at all*)